# OpenCV cv2.setMouseCallback() won't show up

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am learning OpenCV right now and I want to experiment with writing objects on live feed. This is my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cv2.namedWindow('Test')
cv2.setMouseCallback()
```

And this is the error that I am getting:
[image: error]

It says that it cannot find the function. I've tried reinstalling the package/ older versions and nothing has worked so far. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Does it actually raise an exception when you try to execute that code? (Well, it will, but that's because you're missing required arguments, not because it doesn't exist -- it's likely your IDE just isn't aware of its existence)

Comment: `setMouseCallback`   was introduced in OpenCV 3.0, so if you're using an older version, it won't be available in older version, check your `version` by  `print(cv2.__version__)` and let us know if you have newer version

Comment: cv2.setMouseCallback() needs some parameters. I dont know enough about python to tell whether that's important or not for that error message.

Comment: hello guys! Sorry for the late reply i was busy, so @DanMašek no error pops up and i am using version 4.8.0

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?